# Oracle database not recognizing type when using procedure

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, procedure

I declared my types in the package header:

`file_2.sql`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_UTILS
IS
TYPE VECTOR IS TABLE OF PLS_INTEGER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
TYPE MATRIX IS TABLE OF VECTOR INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
PROCEDURE PRINT_MATRIX(p_matrix IN MATRIX);
END MY_UTILS;
```

My print matrix procedure

```
PROCEDURE PRINT_MATRIX(p_matrix IN MATRIX)  IS
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('printing matrix..');
END PRINT_MATRIX;
```

The `PRINT_MATRIX` procedure does a simple `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` to print the matrix; When I try to use my `MY_UTILS.PRINT_MATRIX(v_matrix)` I get the error:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   'PRINT_MATRIX'

In my other `.sql` file I also declare the MATRIX type the same as in the package.

`file_1.sql`

```
set serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
TYPE VECTOR IS TABLE OF PLS_INTEGER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
TYPE MATRIX IS TABLE OF VECTOR INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
v_matrix MATRIX;
BEGIN
--populate matrix, printing it works with 2 FOR LOOPS
MY_UTILS.PRINT_MATRIX(v_matrix); -- error
END;
```

Comment: Please post what your `PRINT_MATRIX` procedure looks like, since the error relates to wrong types of arguments on its call (not types you have declared throughout your package or other sql files)

Comment: @Veverke I just rewrote it to just print a string and I still get the same error.

Comment: @AlexPoole I just copy-pasted the TYPE declaration from my `file_1.sql` (where I have a anonymous block) to the `file_2.sql` where I created my package. v_matrix is declared as MATRIX in the anonymous block as in the last lines of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle sees your variable as a different type to the formal argument. To you they look identical, buy to Oracle they are two different types.

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS00511):

> A collection type defined in a package specification is incompatible with an identically defined local or standalone collection type.

So you have to change your variable declaration to use the type from the package:

```
DECLARE
  v_matrix MY_UTILS.MATRIX;
BEGIN
  --populate matrix, printing it works with 2 FOR LOOPS
  MY_UTILS.PRINT_MATRIX(v_matrix); -- error
END;
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. I deleted the other question because it had -2, I thought that score made it an unnecessary/no purpose question.